# How do I report a vulnerability?

Tags: penetration-test, vulnerability

How would I report an international security vulnerability which could cause a lot of damage?

I am asking how & where I would report this vulnerability, not now to create a simple vulnerability. :)) so & I am trying to trade it to free someone.

Comment: What kind of a vulnerability?  A software vulnerability in a software product from a particular company?

Comment: ah it's not i don't know how to explain it 
it's not a webapp vul or something like it's more bigger then that

Comment: If it's a protocol vulnerability (so it would affect multiple products from multiple vendors) then the people to contact would be the maintainers of the protocol (probably the [IETF](http://www.ietf.org/)) and any vendors who implement the protocol. Examples of this being done are Dan Kaminsky's DNS bug from 2008 and the more recent HeartBleed bug. In both cases, much was done in secret by the maintainers and vendors before the rest of us knew anything about it.

Comment: "international security vulnerability" means nothing.  You need to explain exactly where the vulnerability was found (not necessarily what it is) in order for anyone to be able to reasonably help you.

Comment: @Ladadadada Hearbleed was actually an implementation error, not a protocol error. It was a missing bounds check on an array, as far as I remember.

Comment: @SteveDL Yes, and Kaminsky's bug was too but the implementation was common to multiple DNS vendors. djbdns was not affected. Heartbleed was in library code so it too affected multiple vendors. Those were examples of bugs that were dealt with in secret with the vendors so that the exploitability window could be small. A protocol bug would be handled in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *privately* contact the person who manages the software in which you found a vulnerability. Tell them about the vulnerability you found, including how you think it can be exploited and what you think it can do. Give them some time (often in the range of a few months) to verify your claims and provide a solution.

Once they have fixed the issue and a link to a patch has been made available to their customers, contact the [CVE list](https://cve.mitre.org/) and ask for a CVE number if you're out for the glory.

**Edit:** be aware that some software providers are morons and refuse to acknowledge their mistakes, so they try and sue whoever presents them with a vuln in order to quiet them and avoid the shame of having security issues in their software. Some cryptology researchers I've met have had this issue time and again with smart card manufacturers. If you suspect you're facing this type of individual, stay anonymous when reporting.

Comment: i haven't found it on software it's an international sec vul it may bring down part of the web it's bigger then software vul
example like the google network imagine that we only have the google search & the google went down

Comment: As said above "international vuln" means nothing at all. Vulnerabilities arise from defaults in software or hardware, or from software/hardware being misconfigured. In any case there's an entity handling the different components that lead to the vuln existing.